# Auto saving shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have put all my code for saving sharedpreferences in a method `saveData()`, and I thought if I put that method in end-of-lifecycle OS methods (onStop(), onDestroy()) that it will be called automatically whenever the app closes, but it doesn't!
 How do I make this happen?

```
public void saveData() {
        mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(KEY_SHARED_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        mGson = new Gson();
        String s1 = mGson.toJson(t); //ArrayList<CustomObj>
        String s2 = mGson.toJson(g); //ArrayList<String>
        String s3 = mGson.toJson(i); //CustomObj

        mEditor.putString(KEY_T, s1);
        mEditor.putString(KEY_G, s2);
        mEditor.putString(KEY_I, s3);
        mEditor.putString(KEY_SELECT, select);
        mEditor.putInt(KEY_POSITION_T, positionT);
        mEditor.putInt(KEY_POSITION_M, positionM);

        mEditor.apply();
    }
```

I saw this in a youtube video, so it shouldn't be a problem, I can't put the rest of my Activity because its too long.

Comment: try it on onPause() method

Comment: `onDestroy()` is notorious for not being executed, but I am surprised `onStop()` is not being called. As @ParthBhatti indicated `onPause()` is a good option. But, if saving the preferences is not working under `onStop()` perhaps the problem is with your code...but we will never know, because you have not posted your code.

Comment: Can you show your saveData() method, because issue is in that.

Comment: Also in onCreate() I have `if (mSharedPreferences!=null) loadData();` but it shows that mSharedPreferences is null

Comment: Where are you initializing `mSharedPreferences` ?

Comment: before onCreate() - private Sharedprefs mSharedPrefs; Could this be the problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you think that the data is not being saved in your `SharedPreferences` because you cannot read them, because it is always `null`. But there is no need in making the `SharedPreferences` a class variable. Try this and put `saveData()`in your `onStop()` method:

```
public void saveData() {
    //No need to make the SharedPreferences object a class instance variable...keep it local
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(KEY_SHARED_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        mGson = new Gson();
        String s1 = mGson.toJson(t); //ArrayList<CustomObj>
        String s2 = mGson.toJson(g); //ArrayList<String>
        String s3 = mGson.toJson(i); //CustomObj

        editor.putString(KEY_T, s1);
        editor.putString(KEY_G, s2);
        editor.putString(KEY_I, s3);
        editor.putString(KEY_SELECT, select);
        editor.putInt(KEY_POSITION_T, positionT);
        editor.putInt(KEY_POSITION_M, positionM);

        editor.apply();
    }
```

Now call `loadData()` from `onCreate()`(you do not check to see if mSharedPreferences is `null` ... don't even declare it a class variable!!)

```
private void loadData() {
    try {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(KEY_SHARED_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        //If the key is not available neither are the values!!
        if(pref.contains(KEY_T)){
            //read your data!!
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: SharedPrefs as class var was problem, also removed checking if mSharedprefs != null

Comment: Actually its just the mSharedPrefs!=null that was the problem, w/o it it works just fine. Just loadData(); And thx a lot!!! :) But still, I don't get, why that wasn't right!? mSharedprefs were not null so it should've worked

Comment: @Nemanja :: As a class variable  `SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;` or `SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = null;` the variable `mSharedPreferences` will remain `null` until you assign it a non-null object. It becomes non-null when you do this :: `mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(KEY_SHARED_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);`.  Note that in your `loadData()` method you will still want to check if your `SharedPreferences` contains the key! otherwise you will get an error when trying to read it--this will happen the first time the app is freshly installed!

Comment: Huh, interesting. Thx for that. I don't like just fixing the error w/o knowing  what caused it.